# Open CV syntax in google colab

Tags: opencv, image-processing

In the following code, I was trying to print the normalized image, which worked well in the google Colab environment. But as soon as I converted that image matrix to a flattened matrix it simply resulted in an error.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
%matplotlib inline
import os

vertical = cv2.imread("vertical (1).PNG", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
horizontal = cv2.imread("horizontal (1).PNG", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
vertical = vertical/255   
horizontal = horizontal/255

print(vertical) 
print(horizontal) 

vertical_flattened = vertical.flatten() 
horizontal_flattened = horizontal.flatten()

print(vertical_flattened)
print(horizontal_flattened)

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"]=(20,10)

plt.subplot(2,3,1)
plt.title('Vertical Image')
plt.imshow(vertical, cmap = 'gray')

plt.subplot(2,3,4)
plt.title('Vertical_flattened Image')
plt.imshow(vertical_flattened, cmap = 'gray')

plt.subplot(2,3,2)
plt.title('Horizontal Image')
plt.imshow(horizontal, cmap = 'gray')

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The error details are as follows :

```bash
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-c30222345864> in <module>
25 plt.subplot(2,3,4)
26 plt.title('Vertical_flattened Image')
---> 27 plt.imshow(vertical_flattened, cmap = 'gray')
28 
29 plt.subplot(2,3,2)
TypeError: Invalid shape (61746,) for image data
```

What should I do to print the flattened image? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you might want to [reshape](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) your flattened array after processing to the `original` shape as `imshow()` is expecting a two-dimensional array, and not flattened one!

Comment: Yeap, actually I used a binary image which is purely black (in rectangular shape) on either sides and white throughout the center. And the matrix I could print is 0 for dark region and 255 for white region .... [[0 255  0], [0 255 0], [0 255 0]]... And after normalization the values simply gets converted to 0 and 1 instead of 0 and 255. The flattened matrix for the same must have values like [[0 1 0  0 1 0 0 1 0]]. Therefore the image should appear quite vertically arranged ... But why I'm not getting that I m unable to figure it out .